# $C^*$-algebraic tensor product preserves strict inclusions?

Tags: tensor-products, c-star-algebras

Let $I$ be a proper closed ideal of a $C^*$-algebra $A$ and let $B$ be a unital (for simplicity) $C^*$-algebra. We have a natural inclusion
$$I \otimes B \subseteq A \otimes B$$
Here, the tensor products are the spatial ones (minimal tensor product).

Can it ever happen that $I \otimes B = A \otimes B?$

I tried the following:

Let $a \in A \setminus I$. We want to show that $a \otimes 1_B \notin I \otimes B$. It is easy to see that $a \otimes 1_B \notin I \odot B$ (algebraic tensor product), but how can we ensure $a \otimes 1_B$ is not a limit of elements in $I \odot B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the quotient map $q: A\to A/I$, one has that
$$
  q\otimes \text{id} : A\otimes B \to (A/I)\otimes B
  $$
is a well defined, nonzero map, vanishing on $I\otimes B$.  Therefore $I\otimes B\subsetneq A\otimes B.$

Comment: Perfect argument! This shows that $I \otimes B \subseteq \ker(q \otimes \text{id}) \subsetneq A \otimes B$, as desired!

Comment: Do you see a quick way to also see that $I \otimes A \neq A \otimes I?$

Comment: I guess $q\otimes id$ vanishes on $I\otimes A$ but not on $A\otimes I$ (assuming, of course that $I\neq 0$).

Comment: Splendid! Thanks!